# LwIP echo client with multiple netif interfaces, how to select a particular netif interface

Tags: tcp, stm32, hal, lwip

On an STM32H753 I run an example tcp echo client from STM32Cube_FW_H7.
The board however has three network interfaces with different IP addresses, all serviced by LwIP (1x LAN8742 + 2x KSZ8851).

Using ping I verified the correct ports are responding, by disconnecting others.
For example IP 192.168.0.101 is assigned to port 1, IP 192.168.0.102 is assigned to port 2, and IP 192.168.0.103 is assigned to port 3.
In ethernetif*.c, the three interfaces got names "st", "M1", and "M2".

All works fine, but the tcp_echoclient_connect function always selects the 3rd port as the local port. How can I tell LwIP to select for example the 1st or 2nd port?

The tcp_echoclient_connect function calls

```
/* connect to destination address/port */
tcp_connect(echoclient_pcb, &DestIPaddr, DEST_PORT, tcp_echoclient_connected);
```

It then selects the 3rd interface (and IP address).

In tcp.c, the function tcp_connect shows how to obtain a suitable interface:

```
/* check if we have a route to the remote host */
if (ip_addr_isany(&pcb->local_ip)) {
    /* no local IP address set, yet. */
    struct netif *netif;
    const ip_addr_t *local_ip;
    ip_route_get_local_ip(&pcb->local_ip, &pcb->remote_ip, netif, local_ip);
    if ((netif == NULL) || (local_ip == NULL)) {
        /* Don't even try to send a SYN packet if we have no route
        since that will fail. */
        return ERR_RTE;
    }
    /* Use the address as local address of the pcb. */
    ip_addr_copy(pcb->local_ip, *local_ip);
}
```

So I'd like to specify a particular netif (interface).
How can I do that?

When I run the tcp echo server, it uses the right interface.
I can send a message to the corresponding port and it responds back. The wrong port does not respond.

My source
https://github.com/bkht/LAN8742A_KSZ8851SNL_LwIP

Note:
ip_route_get_local_ip calls ip_route, which returns the first netif that matches the netmask. It's the function ip4_route in ip4.c.

For now, as I could not find another way to select a partiular netif, I created a few functions to select the desired netif by name:
In ip4.c

```
struct netif *ip4_route_by_name(const char *name, const ip4_addr_t *dest)
```

In tcp.c

```
err_t tcp_connect_by_name(const char *name, struct tcp_pcb *pcb, const ip_addr_t *ipaddr, u16_t port, tcp_connected_fn connected)
```

In the tcp_echoclient server, I specify a netif name when creating a connection:

```
/* from a specified netif connect to destination address/port */
tcp_connect_by_name("m1", echoclient_pcb, &DestIPaddr, DEST_PORT, tcp_echoclient_connected);
```

But maybe the functionality existed already to specify a netif which matches the netif name, MAC address, or IP address?

Comment: Solved. LwIP wasn't designed to work well with multiple netif's. The function ip4_route is used, which wrongly selects the first netif it can find, so the tcp traffic used two different physical ports for the same source IP address when routed to the same switch (for test). I squashed the bug by implementing an alternative function for it, ip4_route_by_src_ip. Now all works correctly, it keeps the selected netif for a particular IP address. It no longer confuses the different netif's.

Comment: I know this is an old question...  AFAIK lwIP always uses the default netif for new outgoing connections.  There are hooks in place to allow you to implement your own routing table, called from ip4_route I think.  Another option is to use netconn_bind_if to bind a particular netconn socket to an interface.  Or the socket option SO_BINDTODEVICE if using the bsd sockets API.